# installing pod gives error: Unable to find a specification for `GVRSDK`

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-vr

I tried to download and run the sample project

[Page which i referred for all things](https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/download#google_vr_sdk_cocoapod)

But when trying to install the pod it gives the error like

```
Unable to find a specification for `GVRSDK`
```

I am facing same error with some other pod's also
Please Help.

Comment: Did you run pod update from the project main directory?

Comment: Yes i did updated the solution. In next answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solve the issue.

Removed and reinstalled cocoapod.
And also used `pod setup` this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this. Make sure that you have no corrupted repos by running `sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`

Then, instead of running `pod install`, try running `pod update`

Comment: Thanks for replying i tried your solutions it didn't worked , but following solved my problem